# Find out error rate using sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, scikits, scikit-learn

I want to find out the error rate using svm classifier in python, the approach that I am taking to accomplish the same is:

```
  1-svm.predict(test_samples).mean()
```

However, this approach does not work. Also the score function of sklearn gives mean accuracy...however, I can not use it as I want to accomplish cross-validation, and then find the error-rate. Please suggest a suitable function in sklearn to find out the error rate.

Comment: Doesn't svm.predict give you an output of classifications? Why would taking the mean do anything useful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have the true labels in a vector `y_test`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import zero_one_score

y_pred = svm.predict(test_samples)
accuracy = zero_one_score(y_test, y_pred)
error_rate = 1 - accuracy
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, the function zero_one_score was renamed on version 0.13 to accuracy_score (see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.13.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to cross validate a score, use the `sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score` utility function and pass it the scoring function you like from the `sklearn.metrics` module:

http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/cross_validation.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score` [Doc here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score).

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
#create vectors for actual labels and predicted labels...
my_accuracy = accuracy_score(actual_labels, predicted_labels, normalize=False) / float(actual_labels.size)
```

Comment: this is the classification error, how much it classifies correctly.